# How do I preserve folder structure when using Google Apps Script utilities.unzip()

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I preserve folder structure when using utilities.unzip() in a Google Apps Script?

This is what I am currently using:

```
    var files  = Utilities.unzip(zipFile);

    for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
      folder.createFile(files[i]);      
    }
```

However, it is creating the files with their full zipped path, as their name, flat in the main folder, rather then extracting the files into expected sub-folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can help or at least give you some ideas:

```js
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function myunzip() {
  var fullpath = [], filename;
  var files = [
    'folder0/path/to/file/file00.txt',
    'folder1/path/to/file/file01.txt',
    'folder2/path/to/file/file02.txt',
    'file03.txt'
  ];

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    fullpath = getFullPath(file);
    filename = fullpath.pop();
    getDriveFolder(fullpath).createFile(filename, fullpath.join('/'));
  });

  function getFullPath(file) {
    return file.replace(/^\/*|\/*$/g, '').replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '').split('/');
  }

  // http://ctrlq.org/code/19925-google-drive-folder-path
  function getDriveFolder(fullpath) {
    var name, folder, search;
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    for (var subfolder in fullpath) {
      name = fullpath[subfolder];
      search = folder.getFoldersByName(name);
      folder = search.hasNext() ? search.next() : folder.createFolder(name);
    }
    return folder;
  }
}
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
```